# How can I print the outliers of a Boxplot in Python?

Tags: python, boxplot, derivative

I want to print the outliers (green points) of my boxplot but I don't know how:
[boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOvGs.png)

This is my code:

```
flierprops = dict(marker='o', markerfacecolor='green', markersize=2,
                  linestyle='none')

plt.boxplot(derivation, vert=False, flierprops=flierprops)
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: If you know the stats logic behind the whiskers, simply pull the values less/greater than that metric. (e.g. 1.5 IQR)

Comment: How do you mean this "pull the values less/greater" ?

Comment: Here is a bit more research you can do to figure out the answer to your question.  [Box plots](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot). Refer to the ‘Elements of a box plot’ section.

Comment: I'm sorry, but tthat did not help me.

Comment: Fair enough. I've just popped an answer (including an example) on for you ... I hope this helps to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:
There are (n) points beyond the whiskers (upper and lower) and you wish to print (display) the values of these points, from your dataset.

#### Background:

Generally, outliers can be visualised as the values outside the upper and lower whiskers of a box plot.  The upper and lower whiskers can be defined in a number of ways.

One method is:

> Lower: Q1 - k * IQR

> Upper: Q3 + k * IQR

where `k` is (generally) defined as 1.5, and the IQR (inner quartile range) is [defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot#Elements_of_a_box_plot):

> IQR = Q3 - Q1 = qn(0.75) - qn(0.25)

#### Example:

The following dataset can be visualised as:

```
array([ 65.46329369,  91.64897781,  96.85666088,  60.18189851,
        30.53996122,  55.12666144,  63.00161253,  29.97804178,
        ...,
        47.98458963,  37.69556267,  44.26758617,  58.60869412,
        150.        , 155.        , 160.        , 165.        ,
        170.        , 175.        ])
```

[image]

To extract the outliers (we'll focus on the upper outliers), we first need to know the IQRs, which can be found using:

```
pandas.Series(data).describe()
```

Output:

```
count    106.000000
mean      62.569111
std       29.698729
min        0.000000
25%       46.934198
50%       57.002615
75%       69.516237
max      175.000000
```

Determine the approximate whisker values:

```
iqr = (69.516 - 46.934)
upper = 69.516 + (iqr*1.5)
lower = 46.934 - (iqr*1.5)

>>> iqr, upper, lower
>>> (22.582, 103.389, 13.06)
```

Extract (examine) the values of the upper outliers:

```
data[data > upper]

>>> array([150., 155., 160., 165., 170., 175.])
```